# Android app to view site offline and cache selected videos

Tags: android, video, offline

I am looking for an android app that will allow me to view the content of a site offline, including video content and to be able to view the video content in context.  I want to be able to cache all the text, but to be able to choose which videos to cache.  It is fine if I need to do some pre-processing on a server before hand.

The best I've found so far is [kiwix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kiwix.kiwixmobile) which is a viewer for [zim format archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIM_(file_format)).  I can create a zim archive of a site, including video, download that archive to a phone and then view it in the kiwix app.  But it's all or nothing - I can't download the text and then choose which videos to download.  So my current compromise is to create multiple smaller zim archives and the user decides which archives to download.

There are also [various video downloaders in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video%20downloader&c=apps) but it looks like they would download the video separately, so the video would then be out of context from the original content.  Also the downloaders start from a web page, so it's hard to combine with an offline copy of the website.

I've also found an [offline browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gashawmola.offline) but that explictly does not support video.

Any suggestions welcome.